# How to transfer data from user control to windows form using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on an application where I am working on a form on which when I click a button it shows a pop and on that modal **Pop Up** I am using a user control. The user control contains a grid where I want to select a record and fetch the ID transfer back to the main form from where I clicked the form. Here is my code below

> Parent Form

```
 Public Function CustomerCardDlg() As String
                Using f As New CustomerCardsDlg(mUIC, mInvCustId)
                    f.ShowDialog(ParentForm)
                    Return f.mUniqueTransId
                End Using
            End Function
```

> Child Form

```
Public Class CustomerCardsDlg

        Private mUIC As ApplicationInterfaces.UIContext
        Private mPaymentDetailsList As New DataTable
        Private mCustomerCallerService As CustomerCallerService
        Private mCustomerPaymentDetailsList As List(Of CustomerGravityPaymentDetailsModel)
        Private mCustomerIdentity As Integer = Integer.MinValue
        Public Property mUniqueTransId As String = String.Empty
        Public Sub New(UIC As ApplicationInterfaces.UIContext, customerIdentity As Integer)
            InitializeComponent()
            mUIC = UIC
            mCustomerIdentity = customerIdentity
            mCustomerCallerService = New CustomerCallerService(UIC.Context.ProductKey, UIC.Context.UserName)
        End Sub
        Private Sub Populate()
            Try
                PaymentMethodsEmergePayCtrl1.Populate(mUIC, mPaymentDetailsList, mCustomerPaymentDetailsList)
                mUniqueTransId = PaymentMethodsEmergePayCtrl1.mUniqueTransId
            Catch ex As Exception
                Charter.UI.ApplicationBase.Utility.ShowException(mUIC, "Could not load.", ex)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Async Sub Dlg_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
            PaymentMethodsEmergePayCtrl1.Focus()
            mCustomerPaymentDetailsList = Await mCustomerCallerService.GetCustomerPaymentDetailsAsync(mCustomerIdentity)
            mPaymentDetailsList = Ops.Utility.ConvertToDataTable(mCustomerPaymentDetailsList)
            Populate()
        End Sub

    End Class
```

> User Control

```
Private Sub SelectCard(ByVal RecordIdentity As Integer)
            Try

                mUniqueTransId = (From d In mCustomerPaymentDetailsList Where d.Identity = RecordIdentity).FirstOrDefault().UniqueTransId
                ' Get Information from customer card list 
                ' bind the unique transId 

            Catch ex As Exception
                Charter.UI.ApplicationBase.Utility.ShowException(mUIC, "Edit Customer Cards", ex)
            End Try
        End Sub


        Private Sub lgMain_CellButtonClick(ByVal cell As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell, ByVal ColumnName As String) Handles lgMain.CellButtonClick
            SelectCard(lgMain.SelectedId)
        End Sub
```

Here the user will select a card and I want to return the selected **mUniqueTransId** back to parent form.

Answer (score 1):

The `UserControl` is just a control, and as such has no knowledge of anything related to a specific parent form that might use it. You might eventually add it to other forms with different properites defined. Therefore it has no ability to use a specific `CustomerCardsDlg.mUniqueTransId` property.

Instead, you have a few options:

1. Provide a form reference as an argument to the `SelectCard()` method call
2. Have the control set a property of its own, and then make the parent form then either set its own property directly after the method call or update the property on the parent form to return the value from the usercontrol
3. Raise an Event that can be handled elsewhere
4. Keep shared state somewhere separate from any of the forms or controls

Comment: This should almost certainly be done using option 2 or 3 or both. If the form already knows when this data is required, just option 2 is enough. If the form needs to be alerted when this data is available or changed, option 3 should be used. The event can provide the data itself or it can provide just the notification and the data can be exposed using option 2. [This](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) might be useful in understanding how to provide an event.